# WP php include with shortcode is always on top

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to include a table into a wordpress page.
The table includes some php codes as well so want to try doing this with shortcodes.

I do not want to make a page template for this because I want to easily edit the text (in the WP page editor) above and below the included table.

The problem is that if I include the php file containing the table, the table will always be on top of the page instead in the middle of the article. How can I fix this?

```
function include_scams_page_template()
{
    $path = get_template_directory() . '/templates/scams.php';
    $output = include $path;
    return $output ;
}
add_shortcode ('include_scams_page_template' , 'include_scams_page_template');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function include_scams_page_template()
{
    $path = get_template_directory() . '/templates/scams.php';
    ob_start();
    include $path;
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output ;
}
add_shortcode ('include_scams_page_template' , 'include_scams_page_template');
```

**Explanation**:

I guess your code in scams.php produced output that comes to early. `ob_start()` turn's on output buffering, and `ob_get_clean()` ends it and returns the buffer-content.

Comment: WORKED!!!!!! Thanks so much. I would have never guessed it without help.

Comment: You welcome. When everything works well, please consider to accept my answer :)